# if count value of the column is greater than 1, I want to print the count of the column else I want to print value in the field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing a query which fetches details from different tables. In one column I want to print count value of a column. If the count value of the column is greater than 1, I want to print the count of the column else I want to print value in the field.

I want to build a query which will give me count of user_id from table 1 & 2. if the count user_id is greater than 1, then print count (user_id) else print value of user_id

**Table:1**

| user_id |
|    John |
|     Bob |

|    Kris |

|     Tom |

---

**Table:2**

| user_id |
|    Rob |

query result should list count of table1 as it greater than 1. Table2 should list *Rob* as it is lesser than 2

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Are Kris and Tom in different columns?

Comment: made the changes, ignore the blanks in table1

Comment: What does your desired output look like?

Comment: query result should list count of table1 as it greater than 1. Table2 should list Rob as it is lesser than 2

Comment: @ManikandanSoubramaniane See if my answer helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to select user IDs (names actually) from a table. If it's just one row then show that name, otherwise show the number of entries instead. So, just use a `CASE` expression to check whether count is 1 or greater than 1.

You probably need `CAST` or `CONVERT` to turn the count number into a string, so the `CASE` expression always returns the same type (this is how `CASE` works).

```
select
  case when count(*) > 1 
       then cast(count(*) as varchar(100)) 
       else max(user_id)
  end as name_or_count
from mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

`Window Functions` come to mind but since your user_ids are not numbers, you'll run into an issue where you can't have two different data types in the same column. See how this works for you. Make sure to cast the `varchar` numbers back to `integer` if this script is part of a larger process.

```
with cte as 

(select 'John' as user_id union all
 select 'Bob' as user_id union all
 select 'Kris' as user_id union all
 select 'Tom' as user_id)

select distinct case when count(*) over() > 1 
                     then cast(count(*) over() as varchar) else user_id end
from cte
```

---

```
with cte as 

(select 'Rob' as user_id)

select distinct case when count(*) over() > 1 
                     then cast(count(*) over() as varchar) else user_id end
from cte
```